# How to static type dynamic data

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, scala, f#

This may be some specific case.

But how can I map dynamic entity. In a application I need to provide [dynamic forms](http://kelp404.github.io/angular-form-builder/). It  will generate a JSON for form. So, that will be the metadata for the page where this form is being used.

Now, form matadata I can just dump it to any nosql or sql db but what about form data. As, I will never know what will form look like. How, can I map that data with static type and if possible put validation on that.

Means in normal case I know what will be there in form and what user will gonna enter so in that case I map form with model (class) but what I can do in type of scenarios where I don't know what user gonna add or how form gonna look like. I can just dump whatever json is coming from form but what if I like to map with static typing and if possible provide some rules/validation over there.

Please let me know if any further information required.

[Here](http://www.zoho.com/creator/) is specific example of a application that is doing what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If you have no control over what user builds you have no way to map such data to your structures - you need to clarify what you trying to build... but your question may endup too broad - so please narrow down your request. Indeed JSON/XML are perfect to store such semi-structured data and you may be able to ask user to configure validation...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for reply. I have updated question with kinda similar application's link. Please let me know if it needs further explanation.

Comment: I believe I know what you want as I've spent some years as part of relatively small team building one - [InfoPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_InfoPath). So based on that  knowledge I think you need to narrow down the question...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry I didn't mean it otherwise. I didn't get it at first. I will try to narrow down my question with specifications. Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these, I would not use serialization models at all. I would instead use something like [Json.NET's LINQ to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm).

Here's a [blog article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing) about this.